# HTML config form options

Tags: html, css

I have a product slider - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SdNm.png

HTML Code:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/rslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <form id="signup_form" method="post" name="signup_form" action="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="2f8c47702b1f5eb36dad1d8f4ba66211ce0c31af">
            <input type="hidden" name="configure" value="true">

            <div class="vps-box">

            <div class="vps-os"> 
                <h4 class="step"><small>1</small>SSD/SATA</h4>
                <select class="select-vps select-drive" id="select-drive">
                    <option style="color: blue; height: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left:15px" value="47" selected>SSD</option>
                    <option style="color: blue; height: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left:15px" value="48">SATA</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="vps-location">
                <h4 class="step"><small>2</small>Select a Location</h4>
                <select class="select-vps select-locations" id="select-location">
                    <option style="color: blue; height: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left:15px" value="49" selected>France</option>
                    <option style="color: blue; height: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-left:15px" value="50">Canada</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="vps-sliderinfo">
            <h4 class="step"><small>3</small>Configure Your Server</h4>

            <div class="slider-bar">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        var packages = [
                    ['1', '2', '25', '2', '€30.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=47'],
                    ['2', '2', '50', '4', '€40.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=59'],
                    ['3', '4', '50', '5', '€50.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=60'],
                    ['4', '4', '75', '8', '€60.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=61'],
                    ['6', '6', '100', '10', '€80.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=62'],
                    ['8', '8', '100', '12', '€100.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=63']];



                        $("input[name='configoption5']").change(function () {

                            // Windows Plans

                            if ($(this).val() == "55") {
                                packages = [
                    ['1', '2', '50', '5', '€40.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=53'],
                    ['4', '2', '75', '8', '€60.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=64'],
                    ['6', '4', '100', '10', '€80.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=65'],
                    ['8', '4', '100', '12', '€100.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=66'],
                    ['10', '6', '150', '15', '€120.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=67'],
                    ['12', '6', '200', '15', '€150.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=68']];
                            } else {
                                packages = [
                    ['1', '2', '25', '2', '€30.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=47'],
                    ['2', '2', '50', '4', '€40.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=59'],
                    ['3', '4', '50', '5', '€50.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=60'],
                    ['4', '4', '75', '8', '€60.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=61'],
                    ['6', '6', '100', '10', '€80.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=62'],
                    ['8', '8', '100', '12', '€100.00', '/cart.php?a=add&pid=63']];
                            } 
                             $(s).trigger('change');
                        });

                        function _(id) {
                            return document.getElementById(id);
                        }

                    </script>

                    <div id="pgk_full" style="background:url('images/slider-bg.png') 0px 11px no-repeat;">
                        <div class="rslide_r">
                            <div class="selectorbox">
                                <input class="value" id="hvalue" name="hvalue" onchange="s.setValue(parseInt(this.value))" readonly="readonly" type="hidden">

                                <div class="slider" id="slider1" tabindex="1">
                                    <input class="slider-input" id="sliderinput1">
                                </div>

                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    var s = new Slider(_("slider1"), _("sliderinput1"));
                                    var old_value = 0;
                                    var new_value = 0;
                                    var svar0 = 0;
                                    var svar1 = 0;
                                    var svar2 = 0;
                                    var svar3 = 0;
                                    var svar4 = 0;

                                    s.onchange = function () {
                                        new_value = s.getValue();
                                        var pkgid = s.getValue();
                                        document.getElementById('pkg').value = pkgid;
                                        _('line').style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';


if ($(window).width() <= 10400){    
                                        _('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 919) + 'px 0px';
}   else if ($(window).width() <= 960){ 
                                        _('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 799) + 'px 0px';
}   else if ($(window).width() <= 768){ 
                                        _('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 668) + 'px 0px';
}       else if ($(window).width() <= 640){ 
                                        _('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 520) + 'px 0px';
}   else {
                                        _('line').style.backgroundPosition = (parseInt(_('handle').style.left) - 280) + 'px 0px';
}






                                        old_value = new_value;
                                        _('hvalue').value = new_value;
                                        _('svar0').innerHTML = packages[new_value][0] + " GB ";
                                        _('svar1').innerHTML = packages[new_value][1] + " Cores ";
                                        _('svar2').innerHTML = packages[new_value][2] + " GB ";
                                        _('svar3').innerHTML = packages[new_value][3] + " TB ";
                                        _('svar4').innerHTML = packages[new_value][4];;
                                    };




                                    function toSubmit() {
                                        var form = $('#signup_form');

                                        var drive = document.getElementById("select-drive").value;
                                        var location = document.getElementById("select-location").value;

                                        if ( drive == '47' && location == '49')
                                            {
                                                alert("/cart.php?a=add&pid=47")
                                            }
                                        else if ( drive == '48' && location == '49')
                                            {
                                                alert("/cart.php?a=add&pid=48")
                                            }
                                        else if ( drive == '47' && location == '50')
                                            {
                                                alert("/cart.php?a=add&pid=49")
                                            }
                                        else if ( drive == '48' && location == '50')
                                            {
                                                alert("/cart.php?a=add&pid=50")
                                            }

                                    }
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="plan-names">
                        <tr>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(0)" id="p0"></td>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(1)" id="p1"></td>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(2)" id="p2"></td>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(3)" id="p3"></td>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(4)" id="p4"></td>
                            <td onclick="s.setValue(5)" id="p5"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>


            <div class="slider-specs clearafter">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="cloud-spec ram">
                        <h4>RAM</h4>
                        <h2 id="svar0">2 GB</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cloud-spec hdd">
                        <h4>SSD</h4>
                        <h2 id="svar2">50 GB</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cloud-spec cpu">
                        <h4>CPU</h4>
                        <h2 id="svar1">2 Cores</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cloud-spec bw">
                        <h4>TRANSFER</h4>
                        <h2 id="svar3">4 TB</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <p><strong>2 Gb/s uplink on all virtual servers!</strong>
                    </p>

                </div>
                <div class="price">
                    <h4>YOUR TOTAL</h4>
                    <h1 id="svar4">€40.00</h1><span>per month</span>
                    <input id="pkg" name="type3_package" type="hidden" value="" />
                    <div class="button-wrap">
                        <button class="button green large" onclick="toSubmit();" type="button" id="submit-order" />Order This Plan</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code: http://pastebin.com/bquuac4c (Code too long to post here)

I can't figure out how to code the option where if you select SSD or SATA a different amount of disk space will be shown, they then need to be taken to a different cart.php link. For example for this package shown in the screenshot you get 50GB SSD, but if they change the option at the top to SATA then I want to offer 100GB SATA but CPU/RAM/Transfer will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here is that I advice you to do:

Create 2 price sliders and 2 price displays.
Then, when the value of your select that holds the "SATA" and "SSD" values changes, just hide the one or the other.

What you should also bind both of the sliders so that they always have the same value (moving one also mvoes the other).

Then, what you could do when updating changing the select I talked earlier's value is update the "action" attribute value for your form.

This way I think you get something easy to understand and fully working.